# Cannot merge CSV file into one dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using ipython notebook and struggling to merge 208 CSV files into one dataframe. (My files names are Customer_1.csv, Customer_2.csv,,,   and Customer_208.csv)

Following are my codes,

```
    #import module
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

for i in range (1, 209):
    df_i = pd.read_csv('data_TVV1/Customer_i.csv', names = ['Time', 'Energy_i'], parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=['Time'], skiprows=1)
    df_merged = pd.concat([df_merged, df_i],axis=1)
```

But I got an error. 
It says,

```
IOError: File data_TVV1/Customer_i.csv does not exist
```

To avoid this error, do I have to write every files name?..like,

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('data_TVV1/Customer_1.csv', names = ['Time', 'Energy_1'], parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=['Time'], skiprows=1)
df_2 = pd.read_csv('data_TVV1/Customer_2.csv', names = ['Time', 'Energy_2'], parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=['Time'], skiprows=1)
...
df_208 = pd.read_csv('data_TVV1/Customer_208.csv', names = ['Time', 'Energy_208'], parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=['Time'], skiprows=1)
```

Comment: You certainly can't expect Python to magically decide to substitute "i" in the string literal "'data_TVV1/Customer_i.csv'"!  Look at Alexander's suggestion below for one alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your filenames:

```
df_i = pd.read_csv('data_TVV1/Customer_{0}.csv'.format(i), names = ['Time', 'Energy_{0}'.format(i)], parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=['Time'], skiprows=1)
```

Also, for efficiency, I would recommend the following structure:

```
df_merged = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(...) for i in range(1, 209)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Good response!  Suggestion: please update your response to accomodate "Energy_i", too.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that.

Comment: Thank you Alexander!
But I got an error..

I posted it in another question.:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577149/invalidindexerror-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects